# uibutton with image

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I am having a button using IB. Now i want to add an image to the button programmatically. how can I set the button's size of image's size like we do in IB Layout -> Size to Fit . I want to do it programmatically

Thanks..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add an image to the button using `UIButton`'s `setImage:forState:` method and then you set the content sizing using `UIView`'s `contentMode` property.

An example would look like this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];

button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 100, img.size.width, img.size.height);

[button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateSelected];

button.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill; //Look up UIViewContentMode in the documentation for other options

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: For those copy and pasting from this solution, he spelled `UIControlStateHighlighted` wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
[yourButton setImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
yourButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

where the the values for `contentMode` can be any one of the below

```
typedef enum {
    UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
    UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,      // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent
    UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,     // contents scaled to fill with fixed aspect. some portion of content may be clipped.
    UIViewContentModeRedraw,              // redraw on bounds change (calls -setNeedsDisplay)
    UIViewContentModeCenter,              // contents remain same size. positioned adjusted.
    UIViewContentModeTop,
    UIViewContentModeBottom,
    UIViewContentModeLeft,
    UIViewContentModeRight,
    UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
    UIViewContentModeTopRight,
    UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
    UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
} UIViewContentMode;
```

I think this could help you

Answer (score 2):

Sample Code,

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(20.0 , 270.0, img1.size.width, img1.size.height);
[btn setImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
[btn setImage:img2 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[btn setImage:img2 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the *sizeToFit* method of UIButton (UIView actually).